# What triggered this coin toss?

Tags: no-country-for-old-men

In *No Country for Old Men*, the old man at the gas station tries to make a small talk with Anton and it backfires; Anton tries to murder him by offering a coin toss.

I watched this scene a few times, still do not get why Anton becomes enraged.

Comment: Wouldn't call that enraged.  He just doesn't want anyone in his business.

Comment: Agreed. In his line of work, no loose ends.....not even a small talking clerk in a back water gas station....

Comment: Don’t forget Anton has a specific sense of morality and fate, the coin toss and it’s result were already determined at the dawn of time, he’s just going through the motions, that fate has lead him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gas station owner has taken note of Chigurh's registration plate (by asking him about the weather in Dallas), placing him in the unconscious but unenviable position of being a witness to a multiple - murderer on the 'run' (of course it is much more of a chase to catch up with Moss and the money, but the Sheriffs dept are after him). Chigurh realises this and as part of his decision making as to whether or not this potential loose end should be silenced at the risk of more attention, he resorts to the coin toss, which forms part of his ritualistic killing whenever the opportunity presents itself.